# Implementing a password checker in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char pass[99];
    int i, x;
    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter a password:");
        scanf("%s", pass);
        
        // Check if first character is uppercase
        if (!isupper(pass[0]))
        {
            printf("Password Invalid!\n");
            continue;
        }
        
        x = 0;
        
        // Check each character in the password
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(pass); i++)
        {
            // If the character is not a digit or a valid special character, password is invalid
            if (!isdigit(pass[i]) && pass[i] != '?' && pass[i] != '_' && pass[i] != '$' && pass[i] != '!')
            {
                printf("Password Invalid!\n");
                x = 0;
                break;
            }
            x++;
        }
        
        // If the password length is less than 8 characters, password is invalid
        if (x < 8)
        {
            printf("Password Invalid!\n");
            continue;
        }
        
        // If password passes all checks, password is valid
        printf("Password Valid\n");
        break;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

the code is supposed to check if the length is bigger than 8, the first letter is capital and it has a digit or  a special character.The code is giving password invalid for valid combinations....................................................

Comment: Hi @Boo Man, welcome to stack overflow! What valid combinations are being called invalid? Can you give an example?

Comment: Replace `scanf("%s", pass);` with `if( scanf("%98s", pass) != 1)...`;

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr: `fprintf(stderr, "Password Invalid!\n");` (or use `fputs`)

Comment: You first check if the first character is an uppercase letter.  Then you enter the loop, which rejects *all* letters (the loop only allows digits and various special characters).  Maybe it would make sense to allow letters as well?  Replace `!isdigit(pass[i])` with `!isalnum(pass[i])`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to keep calling `strlen` over and over for the same string.  Better to just call it once, and save the result.

Comment: @Boo Man It is unclear whether a valid password contains at least one digit and at least one special character. Or all characters must be digits and special characters except the first character.

Comment: You can check password length first and don't count it iteratively with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are omitting the allowance of alphabetical characters in your character test.  I believe the following line of code:

```
if (!isdigit(pass[i]) && pass[i] != '?' && pass[i] != '_' && pass[i] != '$' && pass[i] != '!')
```

needs to be changed to:

```
if (!isalpha(pass[i]) && !isdigit(pass[i]) && pass[i] != '?' && pass[i] != '_' && pass[i] != '$' && pass[i] != '!')
```

to provide the functionality you are after.

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: As I explained in my comment, `isdigit` can simply be replaced with `isalnum`.  There's no reason to handle letters and digits separately, unless you want the test to take twice as long.

Answer (score 0):

Another test option can be some like this:

```
if (!((pass[i] >= '0') && (pass[i] <= '9')) &&
    !((pass[i] >= 'a') && (pass[i] <= 'z')) &&
    !((pass[i] >= 'A') && (pass[i] <= 'Z')) &&
    pass[i] != '?' && pass[i] != '_' && pass[i] != '$' && pass[i] != '!')
```

Comment: Don't ever write code like that.  Use `isdigit()`, `islower()`, and `isupper()`.

Comment: although this code is "very ugly", it can be more "light" (processing), and/or useful on some "microcontrollers" compilers, but i agree with you .

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with the logic of your condition in `if (!isupper(pass[0]))` you used ! logical operator that would invert you condition logic , so to make it work use this instead `if (isupper(pass[0]))`